# Should we consider "sqlplus" as an Oracle client?

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, sqlplus

I am a newbie of `SQL*Plus` and `Oracle`, and I have 2 questions about them.

(1) Executing "`sqlplus / as sysdba`" command:

```
$ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Thu Feb 18 05:09:38 2016

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options

SQL>
```

Does the `sqlplus` connect an `Oracle Instance` now?

(2) When use `sqlplus` connect the local `Oracle Instance`, like this:

```
$ sqlplus username/password
```

Should we also consider `sqlplus` as a client? If it is true, does the `sqlplus` also read `tnsnames.ora` file? And the requests also forward to `listener` process?

Comment: Err, yeah. Of course it is. It's THE client. SQL*Plus (and svrmrgl) existed long before any of the modern GUIs. Bit of an odd question, to be honest. Though I'll admit that doing a 'conn / as sysdba' is different to connecting 'normally'. If you're bored, you can `truss`/`strace` the process to see what files it reads & what sockets it opens (listener is usually 1521)

Comment: Don't login as SYS ( / as SYSDBA) unless you're going to shutdown the database

Comment: The use of 'username/password' vs '/ as sysdba' has nothing to do with connecting to a local instance vs. a remote instance.  The key to that is the use of "@mydb" in the connect string - with the caveat about the TWO_TASK variable (if linux) or the LOCAL variable (if Windows).

In any event, just to be pedantic, sqlplus (nor any other client application) actually reads the tnsnames file.  It simply passes the request to the Oracle net layer, which takes care of all routing issues, including resolving a net service name (tnsnames entry) into an actual ip address and listener port number.

Answer (score 1):

SQL*Plus is a client that is already available for a very long time. If you use `sqlplus username/password` then it does not use the `tnsnames.ora`. It connects to the local database that is defined in the `ORACLE_SID` environment variable. If you use `sqlplus username/password@SID` then it will search in the `tnsnames.ora` file to find out the location of the `SID` database.

Comment: Not quite right, in that if TWO_TASK=REMOTE_SID is set, it does use tnsnames.ora as if sqlplus user/pass@REMOTE_SID was called.